# What's the proper way to run commands on a remote machine by multi-layers of ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

Say there are 3 machine: 'local', 'A' and 'B'. Only 'local' and 'A' are connected and 'A' and 'B' are connected. And 'local' wants run commands on B via A.

```
# I run ssh A "ssh B commands" frequently, so a function is created for have clearer code.
run_on_B() {
  ssh A "ssh B \"$@\""
}

run_on_B 'echo export PATH=\\\$HOME/bin:\\\$PATH >> \$HOME/.bash_profile'
```

Is there a better way to run commands on a remote machine via ssh? I feel it is easy to make mistake to do escaping `$HOME` or `$PATH` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not really about running remote commands but about quoting and multiple level of parsing. because the command is used to generate a script file.

If the final command to append to .bash_profile, can be

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

the command to append file

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> "$HOME"/.bash_profile
```

passing as literal just getting out and escaping single quotes '

```
run_on_B 'echo '\''export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"'\'' >> "$HOME"/.bash_profile'
```

But function may be rewritten

```
run_on_B() {
    ssh A 'ssh B '\'"$1"\'
}
```